# Cannot debug in MPLab when hex file is imported

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, mplab

I am writing my code in MikroC PRO for PIC v6.0.0 and i want to debug it using PICKit3 and MPLab. I am trying both with MPLab v8.92 and MPLabX v2.05. When i load the debugger in v8.92 and pres the RUN button the progress bar starts moving but nothing happens.

[image: MPLab debug]

MPLab showed a message stating that the project is out of date and should be build, but i clicked NO. After that i got to this point. There are no source files in this project, there is only the project file. I am just using the MPLab's programmer and i am importing the hex file, generated by MikroC.

How can i bring the PICKit3 properly into debug mode and watch some variables?

Comment: How would the debugger be able to debug the source if there is no source?

Comment: Can the debugger use the hex file only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot debug a hex file.  A hex file contains the bytes that are programmed into memory to run the program.  To debug you need and elf file, this file has debug information that cross references memory addresses with source file line numbers and the locations in memory of the variables.

Comment: I am not sure about MPLab, but in most debuggers you can run and step a raw binary at the machine instruction level without debug information (its not much fun though).

Comment: Never underestimate how bad MPLab is.